# Batch processing in grails with unknown number of items

Tags: xml, grails, batch-processing

I'm trying to speed up reading and inserting a large xml in grails. Right now it takes around 130 seconds to process 100,000 nodes. I have read that if I clear out the session and save periodically it could go faster but all of these examples have an even number like 100,000...I may have an odd number so when I use mod the last few don't get added..right now I'm testing using 18,392 but that will probably grow to an unknown number..how can I make sure all nodes get saved

Comment: it would help, if you could show us the code, what you are doing right now or at least if you could point out, what you have read (url, quote) and try to use now.  In general you would flush every N items and one final time. Pick an N, that makes sense for your workload.

Comment: http://naleid.com/blog/2009/10/01/batch-import-performance-with-grails-and-mysql..I'm trying what he is doing at the end of the article..I can't post code because I'm on my phone

Comment: Do you really need to "pass through" grails? Why don't insert them directly to the database using, for example, an sql script? Obviously you need to transform xml to sql before run.